# Downloading source code from Github with cURL etc

Tags: shell, curl, github, wget

Is there a Github mirror that provides faster downloads than raw.githubusercontent.com?

Right now, this command takes forever:

```
 curl -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
     "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oresoftware/shell/master/assets/package.json?$(date +%s)" \
      --output "$dest/package.json" 2> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RawGit is probably faster, if you use the production URL.

https://rawgit.com/